# using to_iso_extended_string with boost date

Tags: c++, boost, boost-date-time

I am trying to convert d2 to a string of the form '2011-08-02' so I can pass this to my sql statement. According to the boost site, to_iso_extended_string should return that format, but I get the following instead: '2011-Aug-02'.

```
date today(day_clock::local_day());
date_duration dd(30);
date d2=today-dd;
std::string to_iso_extended_string(date d2);
```

how then do I convert the date to string in the yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: Fix your test code. It is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just tested this and it prints `2011-08-02` for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::gregorian;

int
main ()
{
    bg::date today (bg::day_clock::local_day());
    bg::date_duration dd(30);
    bg::date d2 = today - dd;
    std::string str(to_iso_extended_string(d2));
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}
```